# How to send notification through GCM to Java EE web app?

Tags: android, jakarta-ee, google-cloud-messaging

Recently I had to port my Android app to Java EE enviroment . But I'm struggling with the notification process . For now I use Google Cloud Messaging to send notification from "Server A" to Android devices and can't find any clear method to send the same notification to the Java EE web app .

Here's a diagram to clarify what I want to do : 
[image]

Any body came through this before ? Please share your thoughts .

Answer (score 0):

Choosing Google Cloud Messaging to send notification is a googd decision. You may implement the XMPP Connection Server protocol. It can receive upstream messages from user's device to cloud. When GCM receives an upstream messaging call from client app, it generates the necessary XMPP stanza for sending the upstream message.

I did some research and found out a java-based server: https://github.com/jarlehansen/gcmutils/tree/master/gcm-test-server

Here's the link for starting GCM with explanation of code: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Comment: I don't think that the upstream messages will serve me. What I am searching for is sending the same downstream messages from server A to both the android devices and the Java EE Web App using GCM .

Comment: Have you tried reading the Official Google Documentation for downstream? here's the link: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/downstream

Comment: yop and my problem is with the generation of the registration token . It's something obvious in Android but in Java EE it is not the case

Answer (score 0):

You can't implement push notification for you web app itself. 
However you can implement them for different client(browsers). 
It's easy to implement gcm push notification on Chrome, you can check [Google's Doc](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/gcm) on that. 
But I don't think Firefox/Safari support gcm.

Comment: Thanks for your time but this scenario works if I am developing a chrome's app but I am working on a project that should run in Java EE enviroment .